# Does IRB call a specific method to produce inspection output?

Tags: ruby, irb

In `irb`, `regexp = /\A\d+->\d+\z/` prints the return value as `/\A\d+->\d+\z/`. I would like to display exactly that string in an error message for non-matching input.

However, calling `regexp.to_s` or `regexp.inspect` both produce slightly different strings. `regexp.to_string` is not a method.

Does `irb` call a method to get the value it displays, and if so, what method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inspect` looks like producing different output because of escape characters. Actually this is the method used by IRB for output, which is easy to prove:

```
regexp.instance_eval { undef :inspect }
regexp
# => (Object doesn't support #inspect)
```

Answer (score 2):

`regexp.inspect` is what you want to use. IRB escapes the backslashes, but if you actually output the string (e.g. using `puts`), those additional backslashes won't be there:

```
>> regexp = /\A\d+->\d+\z/
/\A\d+->\d+\z/
>> regexp.inspect
"/\\A\\d+->\\d+\\z/"
>> puts _
/\A\d+->\d+\z/
nil
```